# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library XXX.so already loaded in another classloader

Tags: java, opencv, tomcat, java-native-interface

I have deployed one web-application, which contains following code.

```
System.loadLibrary(org.opencv.core.Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

Now, I deployed another web-application which also have same code. When it tries to load library, it throwing following error.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-143" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
Native Library /usr/lib/jni/libopencv_java248.so already loaded in
another classloader
```

I want to run these both application simultaneously.

Till now what I have tried:

1. Loaded library in one application and caught above exception into another application
2. Removed jars from both application and put opencv.jar into Tomcat's classpath(ie in /usr/share/tomcat7/lib).

But none of above worked, any suggestions by which I can do this ?

**Edit:** for option two,

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

This line works but gets exception when I am actually going to use that library. That is when I do following

```
Mat mat = Highgui.imread("/tmp/abc.png");
```

And I get this exception

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J
    at org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread_1(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread(Highgui.java:362)
```

Comment: Number 2 should have worked. You sure you removed it elsewhere and that there isn't some other jar in the webapp that tries to load the lib?

Comment: @user2543253 Please check my edited question.

Comment: Can you check if `Highgui` is loaded by the same class loader that does the `loadLibrary`? Otherwise the native methods don't get initialized.

Comment: Hii @user2543253 , for the simplicity I removed my 2nd app. Now I have only one app deployed and it doesn't contain opencv jar. I put it in /usr/share/tomcat7/lib/ directory. Still I am getting "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J" exception.

Comment: How can I check "if Highgui is loaded by the same class loader that does the loadLibrary? " @user2543253

Comment: I've written an explanation in an answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is with how OpenCV handles the initialization of the native library.

Usually a class that uses a native library will have a static initializer that loads the library. This way the class and the native library will always be loaded in the same class loader. With OpenCV the application code loads the native library.

Now there's the restriction that a native library can only be loaded in one class loader. Web applications use their own class loader so if one web application has loaded a native library, another web application cannot do the same. Therefore code loading native libraries cannot be put in a webapp directory but must be put in the container's (Tomcat) shared directory. When you have a class written with the usual pattern above (`loadLibrary` in static initializer of using class) it's enough to put the jar containing the class in the shared directory. With OpenCV and the `loadLibrary` call in the web application code however, the native library will still be loaded in the "wrong" class loader and you will get the `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

To make the "right" class loader load the native library you could create a tiny class with a single static method doing only the `loadLibrary`. Put this class in an extra jar and put this jar in the shared Tomcat directory. Then in the web applications replace the call to `System.loadLibrary` with a call to your new static method. This way the class loaders for the OpenCV classes and their native library will match and the native methods can be initialized.

Edit: example as requested by a commenter

instead of

```
public class WebApplicationClass {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary(org.opencv.core.Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    }
}
```

use

```
public class ToolClassInSeparateJarInSharedDirectory {
    public static void loadNativeLibrary() {
        System.loadLibrary(org.opencv.core.Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    }
}

public class WebApplicationClass {
    static {
        ToolClassInSeparateJarInSharedDirectory.loadNativeLibrary();
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I use ToolClassInSeparateJarInSharedDirectory class in my project? Do I need to create provided dependency or create the same class in my project?

Comment: @rackom I'm not sure I understand the question. Above code is only an example. If you want to use it you create code like this in your own project.

Comment: This setup is not working with opencv4.0.1 any ideas on what can be different there. I am using Spring-boot and trying to load opencv4 into my app. Thanks.

Comment: Don't know. Best to create a new question with snippets from your code and the exact error message(s).

Comment: As of Tomcat versions 9.0.13, 8.5.35, and 7.0.92 there is a built-in solution.  See my answer below for details.

Comment: Also all calls issued to the native code that belongs to the loaded native library must live in the same shared class loader where the native library is loaded

Answer (score 2):

As of Tomcat versions `9.0.13`, `8.5.35`, and `7.0.92` we have added the following options to address this issue [BZ-62830](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62830):

1) Use the [`JniLifecycleListener`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/listeners.html#JNI_Library_Loading_Listener_-_org.apache.catalina.core.JniLifecycleListener) to load the native library.

e.g. to load the `opencv_java343` library, you can use:

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JniLifecycleListener"
          libraryName="opencv_java343" />
```

2) Use the [`load()`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jni/Library.html#load-java.lang.String-) or [`loadLibrary()`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jni/Library.html#loadLibrary-java.lang.String-) from [`org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jni/Library.html) instead of `System`.

e.g.

```
org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.loadLibrary("opencv_java343");
```

Using either of those options will use the Common ClassLoader to load the native library, and therefore it will be available to all of the Web Apps.

Comment: I've spent a lot of time with that and unfortunately it does not work for me. In Tomcat (v8.5.38) logs i see `[info] Loaded native library xxx`, but when it comes to call native method from deployed webapp i got `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.package.XxxxYyyy.methodZzz(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;`. I've been tested options 1 and 2 together and each one separately but without luck. I really had hope that will be working, but it did not.

Comment: @marioosh Are you sure that the native library is in the right place?  Does it work from any classloader or from none of them?

Comment: @marioosh did you ever figure this problem out? I'm experiencing the same problem.  Can't avoid the unsatisfied link error no matter what i do - tried putting the listener in context.xml, server.xml and calling it programmatically but nothing works.  I see it loading the library just fine, but can't call into it.  Very frustrating as it seems like either no one else has this issue or maybe just no one tries to do this very often?

Comment: No luck either with JniLifecycleListener at server, host, and context levels. The final cure to share my native lib was to pack in a jar a wrapper class over the JNI API, and edit catalina.properties for: shared.loader="${catalina.base}/RUN/*.jar, placing the wrapper jar &assoc dependencies (e.g. logging jars) into the ${catalina.base}/RUN/ location. The same dependencies are removed from App WAR's (maven:provided) The wrapper class features a static { System.loadLibrary("myNativeLib"); } section in order to load the native lib in the catalina shared classloader. Works like a breeze.

Comment: It's work. put your jar to ${catalina.base}/lib, then change your  maven dependency of your jar scope  to provided. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck on this exact problem.

Adding listener  in Tomcat (v8.5.58) server.xml file seems to successfully load the dll file (at least the log says so) when Tomcat starts, but when you call the the native method, it fails with java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError.

With or without calling "org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.loadLibrary("TeighaJavaCore");" in my java code makes no difference, same error remain. I include tomcat-jni dependency in my project to enable the "org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.loadLibrary("TeighaJavaCore")" call. While, I guess there is no need to call  "org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.loadLibrary("TeighaJavaCore")" in java code (at web application level) as the TeighaJavaCore.dll will be automatically loaded when Tomcat starts (because the listener above is defined for this purpose at Tomcat container level)

I also check the source code of "org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.loadLibrary" here, it simply calls "System.loadLibrary(libname)".

https://github.com/apache/tomcat-native/blob/master/java/org/apache/tomcat/jni/Library.java

Answer (score -1):

As of javacpp>=1.3 you may also change the cache folder (defined by system property) in your war deployment listener:

```
System.setProperty("org.bytedeco.javacpp.cachedir",
                   Files.createTempDirectory( "javacppnew" ).toString());
```

Note though that native libraries are always unpacked and will be loaded several times (because considered as different libs).