# Tomcat/JNI: Loading native libraries outside of application

Tags: java, tomcat, java-native-interface

I'm tasked with integrating a collection of native libraries into a web application running in a Tomcat7 container.
I already found out that in order to be able to restart the application without restarting the whole server I must load the libs using the Tomcat "shared"-loader, outside the actual application.

For that I followed the accepted answer in this SO question: [Shared JNI library (.so) in Tomcat - UnsatisfiedLinkError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40043849/shared-jni-library-so-in-tomcat-unsatisfiedlinkerror), but no luck so far.
As described I created a small "**DLLBootstrapper**" java class for loading the libs, compiled it and put it in "**CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib**" next to the libs I'm loading.
In the "**catalina.properties**" I set the path of the "**shared.loader**" to that folder.

However when I try to obtain the "DLLBootstrapper" in my application using `Class.forName("msm.DLLBootstrapper");` I get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: msm.DLLBootstrapper`.

What am I missing here?

**Edit:**
Sorry, forgot to mention *java.library.path* is set to the **CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib** folder.

Comment: is that class added in the classpath anywhere?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention _java.library.path_ is set to the _CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib_ folder

Comment: Have a look at my [answer Edit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49437034/7748072) , if it helps.